# Problems faced in using Java Application to process XML File

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am a very beginner and sorry for asking these simple questions. Hope to get help from users. Thank you for your time!

**Q1.** At the console, the result '5' of Control summary appear at the next line instead of next to it. May I know how to get the console result like this [Control summary: 5]?

**Q2.** There is a tag 'items' in the xml.file and it is wrapping the 'item' and its content. The tag 'test' is the root element but how about this 'items' tag? Can anyone please tell me what is it and how to convert into the java application in code?

**XML File**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns="http://www.stee.com.sg/q2.xsd">
 <controlsummary>
  <totalrecords>5</totalrecords>
 </controlsummary>
 <items>
  <item>
   <data>TEST1</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>492.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>420.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>1</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch</loc_desc>
   <company_id>6001</company_id>
   <company_name>Great Real Estate pte ltd</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST7</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>2228.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>2260.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>5</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Taumatawhakatangi­hangakoauauotamatea­turipukakapikimaunga­horonukupokaiwhen­uakitanatahu</loc_desc>
   <company_id>5010</company_id>
   <company_name>Altitude Fulle Coverage</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST3</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>1241.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>1021.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>3</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Chargoggagoggmanchauggagoggchaubunagungamaugg</loc_desc>
   <company_id>5111</company_id>
   <company_name>Big Beeing Craze Food Mania</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST5</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>550.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>0.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>0</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Tweebuffelsmeteenskootmorsdoodgeskietfontein</loc_desc>
   <company_id>73</company_id>
   <company_name>Monotone Classic Paper Producer</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST6</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>3664.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>3450.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>6</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Pekwachnamaykoskwaskwaypinwanik</loc_desc>
   <company_id>104</company_id>
   <company_name>No Name Futuristic Para</company_name>
  </item>
 </items>
</test>
```

**Java Application**

```js
package question2_try1;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ProcessXML {

 public static void main (String[] args) {
  
  try {
   File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ST eletronics\\Q2_20170206112222.xml");
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
   
   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
   
   System.out.println("Root element :" +doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
   
   //controlsummary & items
   
   
   System.out.println("Control summary :" +doc.getElementsByTagName("controlsummary").item(0).getTextContent());
   
   
   
   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
   
   System.out.println("----------------------------");
   
   for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

     Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

     System.out.println("Data : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Data datetime : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("data_datetime").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total a : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_a").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total a in unit : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_a_in_unit").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total b : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_b").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total b in unit : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_b_in_unit").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Loc id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("loc_id").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Loc desc : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("loc_desc").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Company id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("company_id").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Company Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("company_name").item(0).getTextContent());

    }
   }
   
  }catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
 } 
}
```

```js
Console:
Root element :test
Control summary :
  5
----------------------------

Current Element :item
Data : TEST1
Data datetime : 20120901000000
Total a : 492.00
Total a in unit : TONNES
Total b : 420.00
Total b in unit : TONNES
Loc id : 1
Loc desc : Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch
Company id : 6001
Company Name : Great Real Estate pte ltd

Current Element :item
Data : TEST7
Data datetime : 20120901000000
Total a : 2228.00
Total a in unit : TONNES
Total b : 2260.00
Total b in unit : TONNES
Loc id : 5
Loc desc : Taumatawhakatangi­hangakoauauotamatea­turipukakapikimaunga­horonukupokaiwhen­uakitanatahu
Company id : 5010
Company Name : Altitude Fulle Coverage

Current Element :item
Data : TEST3
Data datetime : 20120901000000
Total a : 1241.00
Total a in unit : TONNES
Total b : 1021.00
Total b in unit : TONNES
Loc id : 3
Loc desc : Chargoggagoggmanchauggagoggchaubunagungamaugg
Company id : 5111
Company Name : Big Beeing Craze Food Mania

Current Element :item
Data : TEST5
Data datetime : 20120901000000
Total a : 550.00
Total a in unit : TONNES
Total b : 0.00
Total b in unit : TONNES
Loc id : 0
Loc desc : Tweebuffelsmeteenskootmorsdoodgeskietfontein
Company id : 73
Company Name : Monotone Classic Paper Producer

Current Element :item
Data : TEST6
Data datetime : 20120901000000
Total a : 3664.00
Total a in unit : TONNES
Total b : 3450.00
Total b in unit : TONNES
Loc id : 6
Loc desc : Pekwachnamaykoskwaskwaypinwanik
Company id : 104
Company Name : No Name Futuristic Para
```

Comment: It's best to only ask one question by post. For your first question, one way to avoid the linefeed and extra space would be to select the `totalRecords` tag inside your `controlSummary` instead of the `controlSummary` itself which contains said linefeed and spaces.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for your guideline. Then how should I code the <totalRecords> inside the <controlsummary> tag?

Comment: The root element should be <items> or <test>? If one of it is root element, the another one is just element?

Comment: The root element of your XML Document is the `test` node as displayed. Both are elements, but only `test` contains all the other elements. I haven't used DOM in ages so I'm not sure I can help you much more without spending more time than I have at hands, sorry.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for your time and replies!!!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question - you can just use the totalRecords tag directly and it should work.

```
System.out.println("Control summary :" +doc.getElementsByTagName("totalrecords").item(0).getTextContent());
```

For your second question - items is just a list of item (child element). Test is your root tag (as you have already mentioned) and items is just another tag which got multiple child element. You can have multiple different parent tags which can have multiple child element.

I am updating your XML to add a new tag prices in the end to give you an example. It contains two child element of price. I have also updated the code to read the block. The code also contains the answer to your first question.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns="http://www.stee.com.sg/q2.xsd">
 <controlsummary>
  <totalrecords>5</totalrecords>
 </controlsummary>
 <items>
  <item>
   <data>TEST1</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>492.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>420.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>1</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch</loc_desc>
   <company_id>6001</company_id>
   <company_name>Great Real Estate pte ltd</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST7</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>2228.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>2260.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>5</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Taumatawhakatangi­hangakoauauotamatea­turipukakapikimaunga­horonukupokaiwhen­uakitanatahu</loc_desc>
   <company_id>5010</company_id>
   <company_name>Altitude Fulle Coverage</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST3</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>1241.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>1021.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>3</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Chargoggagoggmanchauggagoggchaubunagungamaugg</loc_desc>
   <company_id>5111</company_id>
   <company_name>Big Beeing Craze Food Mania</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST5</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>550.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>0.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>0</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Tweebuffelsmeteenskootmorsdoodgeskietfontein</loc_desc>
   <company_id>73</company_id>
   <company_name>Monotone Classic Paper Producer</company_name>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data>TEST6</data>
   <data_datetime>20120901000000</data_datetime>
   <total_a>3664.00</total_a>
   <total_a_in_unit>TONNES</total_a_in_unit>
   <total_b>3450.00</total_b>
   <total_b_in_unit>TONNES</total_b_in_unit>
   <loc_id>6</loc_id>
   <loc_desc>Pekwachnamaykoskwaskwaypinwanik</loc_desc>
   <company_id>104</company_id>
   <company_name>No Name Futuristic Para</company_name>
  </item>
 </items>
 <prices>
   <price>
    <data>TEST5</data>
    <unitPrice>5</unitPrice>
   </price>
    <price>
    <data>TEST7</data>
    <unitPrice>15</unitPrice>
   </price>
</prices>
</test>
```

Updated Code

```js
package question2_try1;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ProcessXML {

 public static void main (String[] args) {
  
  try {
   File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ST eletronics\\Q2_20170206112222.xml");
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
   
   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
   
   System.out.println("Root element :" +doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
   
   //controlsummary & items
   
   
   System.out.println("Control summary :" +doc.getElementsByTagName("totalrecords").item(0).getTextContent());
   
   
   
   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
   
   System.out.println("----------------------------");
   
   for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

     Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

     System.out.println("Data : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Data datetime : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("data_datetime").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total a : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_a").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total a in unit : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_a_in_unit").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total b : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_b").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Total b in unit : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("total_b_in_unit").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Loc id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("loc_id").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Loc desc : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("loc_desc").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Company id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("company_id").item(0).getTextContent());
     System.out.println("Company Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("company_name").item(0).getTextContent());

    }
   }
       NodeList npricesList = doc.getElementsByTagName("price");
  
  System.out.println("============[- _ -]======================");
  
  for (int temp = 0; temp < npricesList.getLength(); temp++) {

   Node nNode = npricesList.item(temp);
   
   System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

   if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

    System.out.println("Data : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0).getTextContent());
    System.out.println("price : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("unitPrice").item(0).getTextContent());
    

   }
  }
   
  }catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
 } 
}
```